# Import of my own components fails in react native project

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have the folder `TestApp` where I've created my react native test app, so the index file is located at `TestApp/index.ios.js`, I have a component declared in another path `TestApp/UIComponents/StartScreen/StartScreen.jsx`.
When I am trying to import the component `StartScreen` in `index.ios.js` file it gives the error:

> Requiring unknown module
>   "./UIComponents/StartScreen/StartScreen.jsx".If you are sure the
>   module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".
>   unknownModuleError
>       require.js:147 loadModuleImplementation
>       require.js:88 guardedLoadModule
>       require.js:65
>   _require
>       require.js:49 
>       index.android.js:18 loadModuleImplementation
>       require.js:122 guardedLoadModule
>       require.js:58
>   _require
>       require.js:49 global code
>       require-0.js:1

StartScreen.jsx content:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class StartScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Some text</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default StartScreen;
```

index.ios.js content:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';
import StartScreen from './UIComponents/StartScreen/StartScreen.jsx';

class VertuoseApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StartScreen/>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Vertuose', () => VertuoseApp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without the .jsx extension in your import.

Comment: @AdrianZghibarta I think your file must be saved in .js and not .jsx.

Comment: "I think your file must be saved in .js and not .jsx", you are right, thanks a lot man.